# Attribute android:[...] is not allowed here and things

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

So, out of nowhere, all my .xml file started to have this error.
[Attribute error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omlua.png)
It told me to sync gradle, but my gradle file also have a warning but there's nothing inside. [Gradle Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLJhv.png)

I already tried the invalid caches solution , close/open the file ...
None on these worked.

PS: I can run my project without error.

EDIT : I also have no color in my IDE expect orange/yellow for text & i can't CRTL+CLICK anymore.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Have you declared the `android` namespace like `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` on your root view?

Comment: Clean the project and then Rebuild.

Comment: @DarShan, yes, all my xml file are like this, i also don't have anymore the " right click -> new -> ... " there are no shortcut anymore.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal, yes I also tried that too but nothing changed, thanks tho !

Comment: I have also faced it many times but that worked for me. I don't know about current problems since I don't use XML anymore.